# Ruby on Rails - Devise welcome email to new users with reset password in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin

Im using RoR 3.2.3 and Devise and Active Admin is working great.
However, there is something I am not getting.

In my app, users **cannot** register themselves, only an Admin can register other users.
This is all working, the Admin goes into the Active Admin panel->Users->New and fills the username and email and clicks "Create".
In order to give the customer the option of clreating his new password I'm using in mt AA user model:

```
after_create { |user| user.send_reset_password_instructions }


def password_required?
  new_record? ? false : super
end
```

However, I don't want the email to send the text that devise uses, but rather a welcoming text and not something like "A link to change your password has been requested..." as there was no password to begin with.

In short, I want to use the `send_reset_password_instructions`devise method *without* using it's `devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions` view for when a *new user is created*.

However if the user forgets his password then he clicks the "Forgot Password" link and an email is to be sent with that default text already provided by Devise.

Any tips on how to make this work?

Thanks in advance,
Regards

Comment: At the moment I've mended this issue y using the  `samesend_reset_password_instructions` method and in it's view, i've added `<%if @resource.sign_in_count == 0%> (...)*my text* <%else%> devise custom text for actually forgotten passwords`. This works, but its far-fetched. Any other options?

Answer (score 2):

Its very simple actually, set `config.scoped_views = true` in config/initializers/devise.rb

Then run

```
  rails g devise:views users
```

this will generate all the views files devise uses, you can make changes to the

`app/views/users/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` file to what you need or any other file you wish to change.